# Get filtered object from a ForeignKey relation in django template

Tags: django

I am having a problem with [djangos design choice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224003/688161) not to allow model filtering in templates. Actually, I do understand its sense and I do not really want to break it, but currently I cannot see what's the best or usual method to circumvent my situation.

I am having a model `Task` with a foreign key `user_solutions` to another model `Solution`. Now I am iterating over all Tasks and if the user already has a solution for this task, I want to display both a tick and the link to his solution. Somewhat like this:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    {{ task.title }}
    {% if task.user_solutions.filter(author=author).count() > 0 %}
        Tick!
        {{ task.user_solutions.get(author=author).get_absolute_url }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Yes, it looks cruel querying the database two times for the same information and django template does not accept it like this (correctly).

However, the other approaches to not seem to work either:

- I cannot add a method `Task.get_current_user_solution()`, because in the model I do not know which user is logged in
- I cannot add a method `Task.get_user_solution(user)`, because I cannot pass arguments through the template
- I cannot query information in the view and save it into a dictionary `current_users_solutions` (with `Task.id` as index), because in the template, I cannot use combined variables to access dictionaries (and the index to access it would of course be `task.id`)

So what else is there I can do? From the linked article I can only see that I could add a new template tag to allow querying from the template, but as said, I actually would like to follow djangos design principle if possible.

Comment: You can define a method on the model called `get_current_user_solution(self, user)` and put the user in from the view.

Comment: Every solution I've come up with for this kind of problem involves adding information in the view.  Sometimes it's simple and a single context variable and some if tags can handle it, but for more sophisticated stuff I usually end up iterating through all my objects as you're discussing - either retrieving the solutions then or just saving the user in member data.  A way to pass the request object to object methods called from a template would be a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django way to do this is to create a custom template tag that accepts a user parameter and filters the queryset appropriately. It's just a couple of lines of code.

Django isn't dogmatic about "no logic in templates" (dogmaticism is frowned on in Python generally, aka "practicality beats purity"). It doesn't provide the ability to do that sort of thing natively in the template language, but that's why it has custom template tags at all: if your design requires it, and the simplest way to do it would be to query from the template, then that's what you should do.

Comment: "dogmaticism is frowned on in Python generally" Probably the reason why I prefer Python over many languages.

Comment: Solved my problem in combination with `with task|user_solution:user as users_solution`, because I wanted to further call `users_solution.get_absolute_url` (and possibly later also `.title`) on the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can add whatever you want to your tasks while in the view, so, in views.py, you could do something like this:

```
# in views.py
for task in tasks:
    if task.user_solutions.filter(author=author).count() > 0:
        task.is_this_users = True
        task.url = task.user_solutions.get(author=author).get.absolute_url
```

and then in your template:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    {{ task.title }}
    {% if task.is_this_users %}
        Tick!
        {{ task.url }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use django template tags like this:
> templatetags.py
> @register.inclusion_tag("template.html")
> def task_def(request):
> task = user_solutions.filter(author=author).count()
> if task >0:
> task.is_this_users = True
> task_url = task.user_solutions.get(author=author).get.absolute_url
> return {'task_url': task_url}
>
> in the template file (.html)
> {% load templatetags %}
> and now you can use your return result here like you want
> {% for element in task_url %}