# How to access data from filter in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

using this in template `{{ filter.data }}` giving me result as below:

```
<QueryDict: {'location__icontains': ['Phnom Penh']}>
```

What should I do to get the value `Phnom Penh` instead of `QueryDict`?

Comment: It will be helpful to answer this questions if you can share the sample code for model and view.

Answer (score 0):

You should only pass on already fetched data to the template, [it's not intended nor possible to filter data in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224003/10400050) as it should be done in the view or the model.