# Django filter and display in template if object exists

Tags: python, django

models.py:

```
class Level(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    badge = models.ImageField()
    locked_badge = models.ImageField()
    timestamp=
    models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False,blank=True, 
    null=True)
    unlock = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="A")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student:level-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class ToDo(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    timestamp = 
    models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False,blank=True, 
    null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #Post.objects.all() = super(PostManager, self).all()
        return super(PostManager, 
        self).filter(draft=False).filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())



class Task(models.Model):
     level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     todo = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     content = models.TextField()
     timestamp = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
     datestamp = models.DateField( auto_now=True)
     like = 
     models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='user_likes',blank=True)
     is_verified=models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title

     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student:dashboard')
        objects = PostManager()

     @property
     def comments(self):
        instance = self
        qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
        return qs

     @property
     def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = 
        ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type
```

My views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def StudentLevelDetailView(request,pk=None):

    if not request.user.is_client:
        return HttpResponse("You are in trainer account")

    else:
        Client=ClientProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        subscription=Client.subscription
        instance = get_object_or_404(Level, pk=pk)

        todos=ToDo.objects.filter(level=instance)
        tasks=Task.objects.filter(todo=todos,level=instance)


        notifications =  
        Notification.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
        .filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
        acceptnotify = Addnotify.objects
       .filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
       follownotify = FollowNotify.objects
       .filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
       hubnotifications = HubNotify.objects
       .filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
       newnotifications = int(
       Notification.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
       .filter(receiver=request.user, viewed=False).count() +
        FollowNotify.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
       .filter(receiver=request.user, viewed=False).count() +
        HubNotify.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
       .filter(receiver=request.user, viewed=False).count() +
         Addnotify.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
       .filter(receiver=request.user, viewed=False).count())

        global is_paid_member
        global is_paid_fellow
        context = {
         'paidmember':is_paid_member,
         'paidfellow': is_paid_fellow,
         'task': instance,
         'tasks':tasks,
         'notifications': notifications,
         'newnotify': newnotifications,
         'completed':False,
         'subscription': subscription,
         'hubnotify': hubnotifications,
         'acceptnotify': acceptnotify,
         'follownotify': follownotify,
     }

        return render(request,'task_list.html',context)
```

template:

```
 {% for obj in task.todo_set.all %}
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button style="width: 100%;" class="btn" data- 
toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ obj.id }}" aria-expanded="true">
    #Only display based on condition        
<span class="mytaskbutton"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> 
 </span></i> &nbsp;
 {{ obj.name }}
        </button>
        </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="{{ obj.id }}" class="collapse" aria- 
  labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
            {{ obj.description }}
        <div>
        <a data-click="swal-taskcompleted" href="{% url 'student:task- 
  form' task.id obj.id %}" style="width: 100%;" type="button" 
  class="btn btn-primary">Proceed</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Task getting saved when form is filled:

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
 def TaskCreateView(request,pk,todo_id):
     if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('accounts:index')
     elif User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk, 
        mentor__isnull=True).exists():
        instance = get_object_or_404(Level, pk=pk)
        sweetify.error(request, 'You have not added a trainer yet')
        print("TRAINER ILADA")


        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
     else:
       instance = get_object_or_404(Level, pk=pk)
       qs = instance.todo_set.get(id=todo_id)
       #user = Task.objects.filter(student=request.user)
       todo = Task.objects.filter(todo=qs, student=request.user)

       print("TODO COUNT",todo.count())

     if todo.exists():
        print("TODO COUNT ALRAESY EXISTA", todo.count())
        messages.error(request, 'You already completed this task')
        return redirect('student:level-detail',pk=instance.id)

     form = StudentTaskForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.student = request.user
        obj.todo = qs
        obj.level = instance
        obj.save()



    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Images,
                                        form=ImageForm,min_num=0,
                                 max_num=3,  
    validate_min=True,extra=3)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                           queryset=Images.objects.none())
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            try:
                image = form['image']

                Images.objects.create(post=todo[0],image=image)
            except KeyError:
                pass
         return redirect('student:dashboard')
     else:
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Images.objects.none())

        notifications = 
Notification.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
       .filter(receiver=request.user)
       newnotifications = int(
       Notification.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
       .filter(receiver=request.user, viewed=False).count() +
       FollowNotify.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
    .filter(receiver=request.user, viewed=False).count() +
    HubNotify.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
   .filter(receiver=request.user, viewed=False).count() +
    Addnotify.objects.exclude(sender=request.user)
   .filter(receiver=request.user, viewed=False).count())

   hubnotifications=HubNotify.objects
   .filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
    acceptnotify = Addnotify.objects
  .filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
   follownotify = FollowNotify.objects
  .filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-timestamp')
  counts=int(todo.count())

 context={
    'form': form,
    "qs": qs,
    'todo':todo,
    'formset': formset,
    'notifications': notifications,
    'hubnotify': hubnotifications,
    'newnotify': newnotifications,
    'acceptnotify': acceptnotify,
    'follownotify': follownotify,

}


return render(request,'task_form.html',context)
```

StudentTaskForm is a model form .Has model as Task

I have 3 models. Todo, Level, and Task. Each Level contains many 'todos'. Tasks are basically completed todos. So if a todo is completed, it is saved as a Task. I want the check icon in the 'todo' list be displayed if 'todo' is already completed, that is if this 'todo' is saved as a task. The icon with class "fas fa-check" specifically should be displayed only if this todo is completed. The 'todos' are displayed as a list. In the template, the Level is passed as 'task'... So all the 'todos' in the level are pulled by task.todo_set.all...  I want the 'todos' that are also in the Task which is basically all the completed todos to have the check

Comment: Oh, so what does your view look like? It seems like all of this could be handled in your view.

Comment: I have updated it in my question. @CarlBrubaker

Comment: so you want a check for every `obj` in `{% for obj in task.todo_set.all %}`?

Comment: yes...Just one thing...task is actually Level here...All Tasks ,im passing as tasks @CarlBrubaker

Comment: Sorry..  That is not what i want.I dont want check for every objects... For Task model there is a foreign key to Todo...I m displaying the todoset of the level.....I want the check for only the todos that are saved in Task which means a todo has been completed @CarlBrubaker

Comment: Can there only be one `task` per `todo`?

Comment: One Task with that user and todo @CarlBrubaker

Comment: I will update question with the form save

Comment: tasks = Task.objects.filter(student=request.user,level=instance)
        print("TASKS",tasks.count())
        When i do this i get the correct number of completed todos.Now how do i implement..@CarlBrubaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  tasks = Task.objects.filter(student=request.user,level=instance).only("todo")
  list=[]
  for task in tasks:
     list.append(task.todo)
```

This worked for me. I add all `todos` from  the filtered `tasks` to a `list` and then pass this list to the `template`. Then I just had to compare

```
 {% if obj in list %}
  #display check
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking to display all `todos` in a `level` to a `student` with `checks` next to those that are completed.

view

```
# find all todos for level.
todos=ToDo.objects.filter(level=instance)
# lists to hold todos.
complete = []
incomplete = []
# Separate complete and incomplete todos.
for todo in todos:
    # Check if task exists to signify complete.
    if Task.objects.filter(student=student, todo=todo).exists():
        complete.append(todo)
    else:
        # If no task, add to incomplete.
        incomplete.append(todo)

# Send both lists to template.
{'complete': complete, 'incomplete': incomplete}
```

template

```
{% for c in complete %}
  <!-- If complete make it checked. -->
  <div><input type="checkbox" checked>Todo Detail</div>
{% endfor %}
{% for i in incomplete %}
  <!-- If incomplete leave it unchecked. -->
  <div><input type="checkbox">Todo Detail</div>
{% endfor %}
```

As far as protected checked `checkboxes`, Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly) to see what works for you.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: The task model is actually only to use model forms. So only when the user fills out a form, an object gets saved as task which is equavalent to completing a todo. So is this boolean field necessary?

Comment: how to get only todo fields from the filtered Task objects...By this i can compare {% if obj in filteredtodo %}

Comment: Are you sure you can do filtering inside templates?

Comment: Oops. No. Check this out. [template filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223990/how-do-i-perform-query-filtering-in-django-templates)

Comment: Ok last attempt. I'm going to delete most of my comments as they seem irrelevant now.

Comment: No need ..I have completed this issue .Help me with my new question :p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122774/check-if-all-objects-belong-to-a-list-django   .Check this

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This Link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53122774/check-if-all-objects-belong-to-a-list-django