# ForeignKey filtering in django models

Tags: python, jquery, templates, django-models, filter

i have two models university and college and in college models have University ForeignKey in college models 
than i have to filter in frontend i choose university 1 than show me all first university related colleges

```
class University(models.Model):
    university_name     =   models.CharField(max_length = 128)
     def __str__(self):
        return self.university_name
```

this is my college models -

```
class College(models.Model):
    university_name     =   models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    college_name        =   models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.college_name
```

In frontend, html page if i chose university 1 than show all colleges list related in this university

Comment: Your question isn't clear - do you want all colleges related to a particular university? If so, then if you call that university object `my_university`, then you just want `College.objects.filter(university_name=my_university)`

Comment: in university table i have 4 university and if i click 1st university than it will show all college list which is in 1st university, and if i click 2nd university than show all college list related to 2nd university

Comment: well you will probably want Ajax to do that, but the view function that returns the Ajax response will do exactly what I said above. You just need to send the id of the university object (by POST or GET) and in the view, get the university of that id and do the filter operation I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Robin i will do like that

Comment: i have one more issue, how can i filter data in templates

Comment: you don't - you do the filtering in the view and pass the result to the template

Comment: can u suggest me reference, how to filtering data in templates,

Comment: I already said, by default you can't. There is some discussion here (although it's quite old), including some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223990/how-do-i-perform-query-filtering-in-django-templates . But as I said there is no need for anything complicated here, just do your filtering in the view, as I've already said.