# How to filter and count query set in django template?

Tags: django, templates, filter, count

I have this model:

```
class Application(Model):
    is_paid = BooleanField(default=False)
```

and this view:

```
def my_view(request):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    context = {}
    applications = Application.objects.all()
    context.update({'applications': applications,})
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

and have this template:

```
<body>
    All: {{ applications.count }}
<!--     Paid:  I want to show the count of paid applications in here. -->
<!--     UnPaid:  I want to show the count of unpaid applications in here. -->
</body>
```

What I want to do is that filter the applications based on the `is_paid` field and count them. I do not want to do it in the view. I want to do it in the template to avoid making view complicated and big. How should I do it?

Comment: You don't. You do it in the view.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223990/how-do-i-perform-query-filtering-in-django-templates

Comment: Maybe post another question and we can see if we can help you out in reducing the complexity of your view.

Comment: I have many views. In each view, a student can do a specific task. For example uploading documents, filling out a personal information form, apply to a program, pay the application fee, etc. Well, If possible, I could pass the student instance to each template and by ```student_ins.applications``` have access to applications. I am showing the number of paid and upaid applications in each view. Well the complexity is that I now have to add to variable to each view. I wish I could do it in the template.