# Django: Grouping form fields

Tags: html, django

I would like to group different formfields like in this example:
forms.py

```
    a = SelectField()
    a.group = "Testgroup1"
    b = CheckboxField()
    b.group = "Testgroup1"
    c = IntegerField()
    c.group = "Testgroup2"
    d = IntegerField()
    d.group = "Testgroup2"
    e = CheckboxField()
    e.group = "Testgroup3"
    f = IntegerField()
    f.group = "Testgroup3"
```

And then in the template something like that:

```
{% for group in form %}
   {{ group }}
   {% for field in form %}
      <div> {{ field }} </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to have a result like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Cj5.png)

Could someone give my alittle advise how to do that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutons here:

Simplest to do something just like:

```html
<div id="group1">
  {{ form.a }}
  {{ form.b }}
</div>
<div id="group2">
  {{ form.c }}
  {{ form.d }}
</div>
```

If you're dealing with a lot of fields though, then you would want to do filtering in the template. There are a couple of options here:

Annoyingly Django by design does not include a `filter` filter as part of the templating language but you can add a method as per:

[How do I perform query filtering in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223990/how-do-i-perform-query-filtering-in-django-templates#answer-16429027)

Something to note, [Jinja is supported by Django out of the box](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#configuration) and [allows filtering like you would want](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#selectattr).

Just don't forget that you'd be sorting by **`field.field.group`**.

Comment: yes, I just made a small example. I think it will be something like 20 groups and 10 fields per group.