# Django Template Language | How to write "model.model_set.FILTER" in a template

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I need to filter through a model set in my django template. Basically, instead of model.model_set.all, I need

```
model.model_set.filter(days=today)
```

ALSO. I am aware that a similar question was asked here:
[How do I perform query filtering in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223990/how-do-i-perform-query-filtering-in-django-templates)

I felt that none of the answers provided sufficient information, and as well as that, some of the most upvoted ones are old and therefore outdated.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

*models.py*

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class Time(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    finish_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    days = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK, default="Monday")

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.start_time} - {self.finish_time}")
```

*views.py*

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def manage_business(request):
        user_business = Business.objects.get(owner = request.user)
        employees = Employee.objects.filter(employer = user_business)
        todays_times = Time.objects.filter(Q(days=datetime.today().strftime("%A")) & Q(business = user_business))
        today = datetime.today().strftime("%A")
        
        hours = Time.objects.filter(business = user_business)  

        context = {"today":today, "business":user_business, "employees":employees, "hours":hours, "todays_times":todays_times}
        
        return render(request, "base/manage_business.html", context)
```

*manage_business.html*

```
    {% for e in employees %}
    <div class="employee-container">
      <div class="flex-item" name="js-jobs">
        <div class="main-text-container">
          <h1 class="name">{{e.user.name}}</h1>
          {% for todaytime in e.time_set.all %} {% if todaytime.days == today %}
          <p class="employee-time">Today | {{todaytime.start_time}} - {{todaytime.finish_time}}</p>
          {% else %}
          <p class="employee-time">Today | No Shift Assigned</p>
          {% endif %} {% empty %}
          <p class="employee-time">Today | No Shift Assigned</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="info-container">
          <h3 class="info">Last Login | {{e.user.last_login}}</h3>
          <h3 class="info"><a id="assign-hours" href="#">Assign Hours</a></h3>
          <h3 class="info">
            <a id="delete-employee" href="#">Remove Employee</a>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* filter in the template: a template should only be concerned with rendering logic, not business logic.

You can prefetch in the view:

```
from datetime import date
from django.db.models import Prefetch

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def manage_business(request):
    business = get_object_or_404(Business, owner=request.user)
    employees = Employee.objects.filter(employer=business).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'time_set',
            Time.objects.filter(
                days=date.today().strftime('%A'), business=business
            ),
        )
    ).select_related('user')
    context = {'business': business, 'employees': employees}
    return render(request, 'base/manage_business.html', context)
```

then we can render with:

```
{% for e in employees %}
<div class="employee-container">
  <div class="flex-item" name="js-jobs">
    <div class="main-text-container">
      <h1 class="name">{{ e.user.name }}</h1>
      {% for todaytime in e.time_set.all %}
      <p class="employee-time">Today | {{ todaytime.start_time }} - {{ todaytime.finish_time }}</p>
      {% empty %}
      <p class="employee-time">Today | No Shift Assigned</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class="info-container">
      <h3 class="info">Last Login | {{ e.user.last_login }}</h3>
      <h3 class="info"><a id="assign-hours" href="#">Assign Hours</a></h3>
      <h3 class="info">
        <a id="delete-employee" href="#">Remove Employee</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the detailed + in depth answer too. Once I test it successfully I will accept your answer.